# Laravel 5 error message if keywords not exist

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, search, laravel-5

I am receiving this message as it is.
I want an error message when I call something that is not databased.

I am new at laravel, i know i have to write elseif condition, but i don't know how.

> FatalErrorException
>
> Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception,
>   caught ErrorException: Undefined variable: yyy (View:
>   /Users/xxx/Work/yyy/resources/views/yyy/index.blade.php)

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class SearchController extends Controller {

public function getSearch(Request $request) {

    $search = $request->input('search');

    if(empty($search)) {
        return "please search something!";
    }

    $searchResult = DB::table('yyy')->where('dateOfReport', 'LIKE', "%$search%")->get()->toArray();

    return view('search.searchResult', ['searchResult' => $searchResult, 'search' => $search]);
}

}
```

Also here is my view.blade file:

```
@extends('layout')


@section('content')

<h1>Detaily yyy Reports</h1>

<h2>{{$yyy->temperature }}°C</h2>

<p>{{$yyy->dateOfReport}}

    <a href="/yyy/{{$yyy->id}}/delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');"><font color="red">Delete</font></a>

    Report created at: {{$yyy->created_at}}

    @if($yyy->created_at != $yyy->updated_at)

    Report updated at: {{$yyy->updated_at}}

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    @endif

@endsection
```

thank you for your time!

Comment: If this is a search results page, you need to handle it in the view. Check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops . `@forelse` with the `$searchResult` looks like it would do what you need

Comment: Please do not deface your post, people have taken time to answer it, if you like you can delete it, link is under your question

Answer (score 1):

this error seems to originate in your view code, not the controller.

you probably use a `$yyy` variable in your view, while you didn't assign it in the controller.
i.e.

```
return view('search.searchResult', ['searchResult' => $searchResult, 'search' => $search, 'yyy' => 'this is your assigned variable value']);
```

Comment: @sersipi you didnt pass a `$yyy` variable to your view.